# Puzzled on the ndim from Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((5,2,3,4), dtype=np.int16)
print a.ndim

b = np.zeros((2,3,4), dtype=np.int16)
print b.ndim
```

Above is my code. the output is:

```
4
3
```

I have checked the page from [here]
([Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-c5f4ceae0ab4b1313de41aba9104d0d7648e35cc))

I expected a.dim = 2 or 3, but it is 4. Why?

Could you give me some hints?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tuple you give to `zeros` and other similar functions gives the 'shape' of the array (and is available for any array as `a.shape`). The number of dimensions is the number of entries in that shape.

If you were instead printing `len(a.shape)` and `len(b.shape)` you would expect the result you get. The `ndim` is always equal to this (because that's how it's defined).

The link you give shows the same behavior, except that the `reshape` method takes arbitary numbers of positional arguments rather than a tuple. But in the tutorial's example:

```
>>> a = arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
>>> a.shape
(3, 5)
>>> a.ndim
2
```

The number of arguments given to `reshape`, and the number of elements in the tuple given back by `a.shape`, is 2. If this was instead:

```
>>> a = np.arange(30).reshape(3, 5, 2)
>>> a.ndim
3
```

Then we see the same behavior: the `ndim` is the number of shape entries we gave to numpy.

Answer (score 1):

`zero`gives an array of zeros with dimensions you specify:

```
>>> b = np.zeros((2,3,4), dtype=np.int16)  
>>> b 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=int16)
```

For `b` you give three dimensions but for `a` you give four. Count the opening `[`.

```
>>> a = np.zeros((5,2,3,4), dtype=np.int16)
>>> a 
array([[[[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]]],


...
```

`shape`  echos back the dimensions you specified:

```
>>> a.shape
(5, 2, 3, 4)

>>> b.shape
(2, 3, 4)
```